# PowerShell way to reschedule tasks inside a Group Policy Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I don't find any PowerShell cmdlet that allows me to edit date/time for a scheduled task inside a GPO. I'm asking confirmation that such cmdlets don't exist or (I hope) someone knows an automated way to achieve the task. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally a way to amend a scheduled task inside a GPO by using PowerShell. Basically it is about selecting the xml file where the GPO has the scheduled tasks saved in the sysvol folder, edit it with the help of the xml linq library to select the right namespace, and save the xml back to its folder:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Linq'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Xml.Linq'

#vars
$domain = 'domainName'
$ADcreds = PSCreds
$gpo = Get-GPO -Name 'GPO-Name' -Domain $domain
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\$domain\SYSVOL\$domain\Policies\{$($gpo.Id)}\Machine\Preferences\ScheduledTasks" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $ADcreds
$inputFilename =  "$((Get-PSDrive 'S').Root)\ScheduledTasks.xml"
$outputFilename = "$((Get-PSDrive 'S').Root)\ScheduledTasksNew.xml"

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFilename)
# skip first line with utf-8
$reader.ReadLine()
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($reader)
$today = [DateTime]::Now
$tasksV2 = $xDoc.Descendants().Where({$_.Name.LocalName -eq "TaskV2"})
foreach($taskV2 in $tasksV2.Where({$_.Attribute('name').Value -ne 'wsus-extraMaintenance'}))
{
    $startBoundary = $taskV2 = $xDoc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq "StartBoundary"})
    $todayStr = $today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
    $startBoundary.SetValue($todayStr)
}
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)

Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\ScheduledTasks.xml' | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\ScheduledTasksNew.xml' | Rename-Item -NewName 'ScheduledTasks.xml' -Confirm:$false
```